# Unity WebPlayer Mac版が一度リロードしないと再生できない

Tags: unity3d, macos

作成中のUnityアプリで、Mac(safari,chrome,firefox)のWebPlayerが再生できません。
しかし、リロードすると再生できるようになります。

Macのログを見ると、再生できない初回には以下のメッセージが出表示されます。

```
loader: unity function UnityBundleSetupScreen load failed
loader: unity function UnityBundleLoop load failed
```

何かこの症状に心当たりある方はいますか。
なお、Windows(IE,chorome,firefox)ではこの問題は起きません。

**実行環境**
Unity: 4.5.5f1
WebPlayer: 4.6.2f1
MacOSX mavericks 10.9.5

カメラとCUBEだけのシンプルな構成だと問題ないので、どこかにMac版ではやっちゃだめな事があるはずなんですが…

Comment: 自己解決しました。

モバイル用にカメラ比率を画面と合わせる処理が入ってたのですが
Awake() のタイミングだと
Screen.width
Screen.height
がMac初回ではNaNになっていました。
Windowsでは大丈夫です。

処理をStart()にするか、
そもそもWeb版には必要ない処理なので解決です。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。

モバイル用にカメラ比率を画面と合わせる処理が入ってたのですが `Awake()` のタイミングだと `Screen.width Screen.height` がMac初回ではNaNになっていました。Windowsでは大丈夫です。

処理を `Start()` にするか、 そもそもWeb版には必要ない処理なので解決です。

---

*この投稿は [@masamune さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/5805/unity-webplayer-mac%e7%89%88%e3%81%8c%e4%b8%80%e5%ba%a6%e3%83%aa%e3%83%ad%e3%83%bc%e3%83%89%e3%81%97%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e3%81%a8%e5%86%8d%e7%94%9f%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84#comment4597_5805) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*